# I want to see my thumbnail size as 600X400. But how?

Tags: css, wordpress

I can't see the thumbnail with it's proper regulation. By default, the thumbnail shown 200X300, 600X1200, 600X1024. If i use  600X1200 or 600X1024 it's not show in site properly. But if I use 200X300 then show properly but the resulation is so bad.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/04d2m8gy7a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would accept that you already have [added this image sizes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) in your functions.php. In order to get the proper image output, you need to regenerate your thumbnails to set the proper thumbnail sizes. Download and install [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) and regenerate all you thumbnails. You only need to do this once.